# Running tests from Visual Studio 2013 builds unrelated projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, testing

I have a c# unit test project that's exhibiting some strange behavior -- whenever I run or debug a unit test from this project, it then proceeds to build a number of unrelated projects (I say "unrelated" to mean that there is no referential relationship existing, which I have verified a number of ways, including the dependency graph) before running or debugging the tests.

This behavior is not observed when building or rebuilding the test project itself, so I'm tempted to think that the only cause would be something specific to the test harness itself (which is stock). Any ideas, community? Even just some pointers to some additional places for me to look to try and figure this out would be helpful-- I've cranked up msbuild output to diagnostic and still can't identify what is causing the unrelated projects to get pulled into build output. Ex.:

Project 'FOO' is not up to date. Project item 'C:...\BAR.xml' has 'Copy to Output Directory' attribute set to 'Copy always'.
------ Build started: Project: FOO, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------

Note that not all projects are 'Copy always' projects, some are doing additional work.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say when you rightclick your unit test project -> Build Dependencies -> Project Dependencies?

Comment: The projects that are getting built are not in the list of dependent projects, but do show up earlier than they should in the build order-- If there was an issue with the explicit project dependencies, wouldn't I expect it to visible while doing a rebuild?

Comment: Well it might be a bug, see [this bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/809777/running-a-single-unit-test-in-visual-studio-2013-causes-entire-solution-to-be-built)

Comment: Yeah, that looks like exactly the problem I am having. I'm pretty sure that's my answer =\.

Comment: If it's merely a question of inconvenience, you can try unloading the offending projects in the solution and they should no longer be built.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is building the project to discover all the tests in solution for the test list, that is why the build of unrelated projects occurs.

As a workaround you could use the 'Run Tests After Build' feature.
You just toggle that button on top of test explorer.
Then build current unit test project (Shift-F6), and the tests will run automatically after the build.
It does not build unrelated projects that way.

[image: Turning on 'Run Tests After Build option']

Another option would be temporarily unloading unrelated projects, if they are not buildable for some reason. This option persists somewhere in .user files.

[image: Unloading a non-buildable project]

Another option is using a third party test runner, such as Resharper's, which does not have this problem.